# CSS: display element without rescaling of a "table"

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an element into my table after a click of an image without resizing this element. But obviously the row size is bigger it.

```js
var lastelementmenu;
    var event_cache_site = document.querySelector('.event_cache_site');
    var properties = document.querySelectorAll(".event_list_view_properties_click");//3 points
    for(var i= 0 ;i<properties.length;i++){
        //evenement au click
        properties[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            var div = this.nextElementSibling;
            lastelementmenu = div;
            div.style.display = "block";
            event_cache_site.style.display = "block";
        });
    }
    event_cache_site.addEventListener('click', () => {
        lastelementmenu.style.display = "none";
        event_cache_site.style.display = "none";
    });
```

```css
*{
    font-size:16px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    font-size:50%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.event_list_view{
 
    width: 150rem;
    margin: 5rem auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.event_list_view tbody{
    background-color: #fff;
}
.event_list_view thead tr{
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12) inset;

} 
.event_list_view_array{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.event_list_view_cell{
    padding: 3rem 2rem;
}
.event_list_view_array thead{
    /*background-color: #f5f5f5;*/
     background-color: transparent;
}
.event_list_view_array thead th{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif   
}
.event_list_view_new{
    background: rgb(3, 155, 229);
    float: right;
    margin : 1rem ;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.event_list_view_new p{
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
.event_list_view_new a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
   
}
.event_list_view_legend{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: left;
}
.event_list_view_properties{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
    z-index: 17;
    position: relative;
    top: -5rem;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
    left: -7rem;
    width: 10rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

}
.event_list_view_properties ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0rem 0rem;
    padding: 0rem;
}
.event_list_view_properties li {
    padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
}
.event_list_view_properties a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: 1rem 0rem;
}
.event_list_view_properties_bg{/*
    background-image: url(../images/icon/properties.svg);
    width: 10rem;
    height: 5rem;*/
}
.event_cache_site{
    z-index: 14;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table class="event_list_view_array">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="5"><div class="event_list_view_new"><a href="?state=new"><p >NOUVEL EVENEMENT</p></a></div></th>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Titre</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Contenu</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Date</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Groupe</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend"></div></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>               
  <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 60%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 5%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 5%;">';
   <tr>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell"> title0 </div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">content0</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">2017-05-11 11:00:00</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">A</div></td>
   <td>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties_click" >
     <img src="images/icon/properties.svg" alt="properties">
    </div>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Modifier</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">supprimer</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell"> title1 </div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">content1</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">2017-05-11 11:00:00</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">A</div></td>
   <td>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties_click" >
     <img src="images/icon/properties.svg" alt="properties">
    </div>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Modifier</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">supprimer</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell"> title2 </div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">content2</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">2017-05-11 11:00:00</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">A</div></td>
   <td>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties_click" >
     <img src="images/icon/properties.svg" alt="properties">
    </div>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Modifier</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">supprimer</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div class="event_cache_site" style="display:none;"></div>
</html>
```

[After clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq0pr.png)
How can I solve it ?
Thanks

Comment: Hi thomas, give us some working code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ho sorry I had forgot a codepen link. I edit my post thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` on that instead, and add `position: relative` to the `td` parent. You may need to adjust your `top` and `left/right` to move the menu where you want.

```js
var lastelementmenu;
    var event_cache_site = document.querySelector('.event_cache_site');
    var properties = document.querySelectorAll(".event_list_view_properties_click");//3 points
    for(var i= 0 ;i<properties.length;i++){
        //evenement au click
        properties[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            var div = this.nextElementSibling;
            lastelementmenu = div;
            div.style.display = "block";
            event_cache_site.style.display = "block";
        });
    }
    event_cache_site.addEventListener('click', () => {
        lastelementmenu.style.display = "none";
        event_cache_site.style.display = "none";
    });
```

```css
*{
    font-size:16px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    font-size:50%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.event_list_view{
 
    width: 150rem;
    margin: 5rem auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.event_list_view tbody{
    background-color: #fff;
}
.event_list_view thead tr{
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12) inset;

} 
.event_list_view_array{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.event_list_view_cell{
    padding: 3rem 2rem;
}
.event_list_view_array thead{
    /*background-color: #f5f5f5;*/
     background-color: transparent;
}
.event_list_view_array thead th{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif   
}
.event_list_view_new{
    background: rgb(3, 155, 229);
    float: right;
    margin : 1rem ;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.event_list_view_new p{
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
.event_list_view_new a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
   
}
.event_list_view_legend{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: left;
}
.event_list_view_properties{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
    z-index: 17;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
    right: 70%;
    width: 10rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

}
.event_list_view_properties ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0rem 0rem;
    padding: 0rem;
}
.event_list_view_properties li {
    padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
}
.event_list_view_properties a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: 1rem 0rem;
}
.event_list_view_properties_bg{/*
    background-image: url(../images/icon/properties.svg);
    width: 10rem;
    height: 5rem;*/
}
.event_cache_site{
    z-index: 14;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: none;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table class="event_list_view_array">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="5"><div class="event_list_view_new"><a href="?state=new"><p >NOUVEL EVENEMENT</p></a></div></th>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Titre</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Contenu</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Date</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend">Groupe</div></th>
   <th><div class="event_list_view_legend"></div></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>               
  <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 60%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 5%;">
  <col span="1" style="width: 5%;">';
   <tr>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell"> title0 </div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">content0</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">2017-05-11 11:00:00</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">A</div></td>
   <td>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties_click" >
     <img src="images/icon/properties.svg" alt="properties">
    </div>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Modifier</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">supprimer</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell"> title1 </div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">content1</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">2017-05-11 11:00:00</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">A</div></td>
   <td>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties_click" >
     <img src="images/icon/properties.svg" alt="properties">
    </div>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Modifier</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">supprimer</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell"> title2 </div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">content2</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">2017-05-11 11:00:00</div></td>
   <td><div class="event_list_view_cell">A</div></td>
   <td>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties_click" >
     <img src="images/icon/properties.svg" alt="properties">
    </div>
    <div class="event_list_view_cell event_list_view_properties">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Modifier</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">supprimer</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div class="event_cache_site" style="display:none;"></div>
</html>
```